# XCode's organizer failed to display correct bundle display name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

The `Bundle display name` in the `info.plist` is currently `${PRODUCT_NAME}`, and I have created the localized `InfoPlist.strings` file and the localized string can be displayed **successfully** when deployed to phone.

However, when I do **archive** and in the XCode's organizer and I am still seeing the `${PRODUCT_NAME}`, e.g. **MyApp** in the sidebar.

Are they normal?

Comment: did you select " Build for Archieve"

Comment: Did You get solution for this question. If any of answer from below please accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is totally fine and is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Do select  Product-> Build For -> Build For Archiving
>
> If The updated file is not come do this It will update in Organizer widow.
>
> Product -> Archive

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the bundle identifier which you have used for your application is still active in your apple developer account where you have created the provisioning certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get there the display name of a library project I have included in my main Xcode project. It's kinda silly, but it stands as my App name in organizer.